# I would like to know about examples of type theory applications. For what purpose was type theory invented? Can you give me some motivations?

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I'm an undergraduate math student.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type Theory was invented as a possible foundation for mathematics. It was later tied to the lambda calculus, and is now a prime example of the [Curry-Howard Correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence). Later yet, it was connected to category theory (especially [higher category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_category_theory)), and is a very active field of research. For more information, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_type_theory) or [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory).

Here are some quick applications:

- Foundations of mathematics (as a computer friendly alternative to set theory)
- Programming Language theory (programming languages are made safer by type systems)
- Homotopy theory (somewhat surprisingly, cf. [HoTT](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/))

If you want more resources, a friend of mine made a github page all about learning type theory. Reading through the table of contents will give you an idea of why people care, and it will also have direct links to resources for learning the relevant material:

[here's the github page](https://github.com/jozefg/learn-tt)

good luck!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Very good answer!! Thank you.

Comment: In what way is set theory not so computer friendly?

Comment: Set theory is ontologically very simple - this is one of its strong suits. After all, it's beautiful to see all of (well, most of) mathematics come from such humble axioms! But because it's so simple, there are a lot of pathologies that we as mathematicians ignore. Since everything is a set, the computer needs something _very_ clever to tell which sets are actually numbers, which sets are functions, and which sets are sets (of numbers, or functions, or, etc). In type theory, objects can be truly different, and we can leverage this to simplify our proof assistants

Comment: @Dan Christensen ^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor In my own proof assistant (DC Proof), I have predicates for ordinary sets (Set), sets of ordered pairs (Set'), sets of ordered triples (Set''), etc. as my only types. Not every object is assumed to be a set. To apply my axioms of set theory to an object(s), it must be declared to be a set using one of these predicates. Over the years, I have not had any problems confusing numbers and functions in formal proofs.